# How to obtain Pay API key from PayPal for Adaptive Payments

Tags: php, cakephp, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am at my wits end trying to get this work but cant understand it. I have to use Adaptive payments in a webapp which is created using cakephp framework. I have API credentials like API Username, Password and Signature. But the main problem i am facing is how to call the Pay API to get the API key which is the first thing required to make this work. I am new to this so i dont have much knowledge about this and after lot digging in google i am asking this question. Can someone please give steps for using Adaptive Payments..

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP example for PayPal Adaptive Payments ConvertCurrency API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789699/php-example-for-paypal-adaptive-payments-convertcurrency-api)

Comment: I tried to use the code in following link, did the necessary changes but it gives error that stream_get_contents() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given. What should i do?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915329/paypal-adaptivepayments-paymentdetail-paykey

Comment: did the prior `fopen()` call succeed?

Comment: fopen returns false that's why its returning a boolean and throwing an exception.

Comment: So either the context or the URL needs fixing.  Should be easy to track down.

Comment: Yup I am working that out. Thanks for ur help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to follow only three steps:

1- You send a PayRequest message to PayPal

> {"returnUrl":"http://example.com/returnURL.htm", \ "requestEnvelope":{"errorLanguage":"en_US"},"currencyCode":"USD", \ "receiverList":{"receiver":[{"email":"david@example.com", \
>   "amount":"10.00",}]},"cancelUrl":"http://example.com/cancelURL.htm",\ "actionType":"PAY"}

2- You receive a response with a pay key.

> {"responseEnvelope":\ {"timestamp":"2009-10-06T14:30:39.383-07:00","ack":"Success",\ "correlationId":"cfe8f8783f1d3","build":"DEV"},\ "payKey":"AP-17266198048308436","paymentExecStatus":"CREATED"}

3- You must redirect the sender’s browser to PayPal to approve the payment.

This would be an example code for step 1 (it works on my local server):

```
<?php

//turn php errors on
ini_set("track_errors", true);

//set PayPal Endpoint to sandbox
$url = trim("https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/Pay");

$api_appid = 'APP-80W284485P519543T';   // para sandbox

//PayPal API Credentials
$API_UserName = "sbapi_1287090601_biz_api1.paypal.com"; //TODO
$API_Password = "1287090610"; //TODO
$API_Signature = "ANFgtzcGWolmjcm5vfrf07xVQ6B9AsoDvVryVxEQqezY85hChCfdBMvY"; //TODO
$receiver_email = "fake@email.com"; //TODO
$amount = 25; //TODO

//Default App ID for Sandbox    
$API_AppID = "APP-80W284485P519543T";

$API_RequestFormat = "NV";
$API_ResponseFormat = "NV";


//Create request payload with minimum required parameters
$bodyparams = array (   "requestEnvelope.errorLanguage" => "en_US",
                  "actionType" => "PAY",
                  "cancelUrl" => "http://cancelUrl",
                  "returnUrl" => "http://returnUrl",
                  "currencyCode" => "EUR",
                  "receiverList.receiver.email" => $receiver_email,
                  "receiverList.receiver.amount" => $amount
    );

// convert payload array into url encoded query string
$body_data = http_build_query($bodyparams, "", chr(38));


try
{

//create request and add headers
$params = array("http" => array(
    "method" => "POST",                                                 
    "content" => $body_data,                                             
    "header" =>  "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID: " . $API_UserName . "\r\n" .
                 "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE: " . $API_Signature . "\r\n" .
                 "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD: " . $API_Password . "\r\n" .
                 "X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID: " . $API_AppID . "\r\n" .
                 "X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT: " . $API_RequestFormat . "\r\n" .
                 "X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT: " . $API_ResponseFormat . "\r\n"
));


//create stream context
 $ctx = stream_context_create($params);


//open the stream and send request
 $fp = @fopen($url, "r", false, $ctx);

//get response
 $response = stream_get_contents($fp);

//check to see if stream is open
 if ($response === false) {
    throw new Exception("php error message = " . "$php_errormsg");
 }

//close the stream
 fclose($fp);

//parse the ap key from the response

$keyArray = explode("&", $response);

foreach ($keyArray as $rVal){
    list($qKey, $qVal) = explode ("=", $rVal);
        $kArray[$qKey] = $qVal;
}

//print the response to screen for testing purposes
If ( $kArray["responseEnvelope.ack"] == "Success") {

     foreach ($kArray as $key =>$value){
    echo $key . ": " .$value . "<br/>";
}
 }
else {
    echo 'ERROR Code: ' .  $kArray["error(0).errorId"] . " <br/>";
  echo 'ERROR Message: ' .  urldecode($kArray["error(0).message"]) . " <br/>";
}

}


catch(Exception $e) {
echo "Message: ||" .$e->getMessage()."||";
}

?>
```

You have many examples here: https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/paypal-code-samples

Comment: I was using the same code but the main problem was SSL was not enabled in my **php.ini** file and that was creating a problem in getting the key! Thanks for your help!